# yas-snippets not loading

Tags: yasnippet

While yas-snippet itself loads, the snippets do not. I tried loading them manually and using the following in my init, but neither loads any snippets. What could be the issue?

```
(require 'yasnippet)
(setq yas-snippet-dirs
      '("~/.emacs.d/snippets"                 ;; personal snippets
        ))
(yas-global-mode 1)
```

UPDATE:

Removing

```
(setq yas-snippet-dirs
      '("~/.emacs.d/snippets"                 ;; personal snippets
        ))
```

fixed the problem.

Comment: The `~/.emacs.d/snippets` dir is include in the search by default.

Comment: Seems to work now by removing SETQ yas-snippet-sirs

Comment: Do you actually have any snippets in `~/.emacs.d/snippets`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Removing

```
(setq yas-snippet-dirs
      '("~/.emacs.d/snippets"                 ;; personal snippets
        ))
```

fixed the problem.